# Decrypting Input?

Tags: python, input, decode, encode

This is my assignment:

Write a program which DECRYPTS secret messages.

It should first prompt the user for the scrambled alphabet. It then should ask for the secret message. Finally, it outputs the unscrambled version.

Note that there are exactly 26 characters input for the scrambled alphabet. All alphabetic characters are translated into their decoded equivalents (which will take a WHILE loop), and all other, non-alphabetic characters should be output exactly as they were without translation.

This is my code so far:

```
decrypt = ["*"] * 26

scram_alphabet = input("Please input the scrambled alphabet in order: ")

while len(scram_alphabet) != 26:
    scram_alphabet = input("Please input the scrambled alphabet in order. The alphabet must have 26 characters: ")

num = 0

for each_letter in scram_alphabet:
    decrypt[num] = ord(each_letter)
    num = num + 1

print()

print("Your scrambled alphabet is: ", end = "")

for num in range (26):
    print(chr(decrypt[num]), end = "")

print()
print()

msg = input("Now input your scrambled message: ")

print()
print()

alphabet = 65

for s in range (26):
    decrypt[s] = (alphabet)
    alphabet = alphabet + 1

print("The unscrambled alphabet is: ", end = "")


for num in range (26):
    print(chr(decrypt[num]), end = "")

print()
print()

print("Your unscrambled message reads: ")

for alpha in msg.upper():
    if alpha < "A" or alpha > "Z":
        print(alpha, end="")
    else:
        ord_alpha = ord(alpha)
        print (chr(decrypt[ord_alpha - 65]), end = "")
```

Ex: Scrambled Alphabet = XQHAJDENKLTCBZGUYFWVMIPSOR , Scrambled Message = VNKW KW BO 1WV WJHFJV BJWWXEJ!

Everything works fine until I get to the last print statement, where it says that the unscrambled message is the same as the scrambled message. I know that the instructions call for a while loop but I couldn't figure out how to use one to decode the alphabet.

Any helpers?

Comment: For what it's worth (and to give you something to check against), this is a somewhat long 2-liner (one if you don't count the import):  `str.translate('VNKW KW BO 1WV WJHFJV BJWWXEJ!',string.maketrans('XQHAJDENKLTCBZGUYFWVMIPSOR',string.ascii_uppercase))`

Comment: Hint: in the third `for` loop, you completely overwrite the contents of the `decrypt[]` array, ignoring the previously entered scrambled alphabet...

Comment: @Stobor: Do you mind elaborating? I'm not sure what you mean, I set to decrypt = [0] * 26 again and it printed all spaces-->"        1      !"

Comment: You may need another array that is built with that loop that I commented out.

Comment: @user2680935 I'm sorry you feel that way - if my answer was too complicated please let me know and I'll try to explain more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as has already been noted, you are clobbering your `decrypt` variable.
However, you are also not building the mapping from the 'scrambled' alphabet to the regular one properly / at all.

Decrypting without using anything more than basic iteration over lists and simple list functions (`index()`) might look something like this:

```
cleartext = ""
for c in msg:
    if c in alphabet:
        pos = alphabet.index(c)
        cleartext += string.ascii_uppercase[pos]
    else:
        cleartext += c
```

Rather than just patching your code, it could benefit from some improvement. I gather this is probably homework and you are probably not expected to go this far, but IMO there is nothing wrong with learning it anyway.

- You are not checking that the input alphabet only contains whatever you consider to be **legal values** (e.g. probably A-Z in this case), nor are you checking for **duplicates**. The user could input any old rubbish and break your program otherwise.
- Your printing and looping is not very [idiomatic](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html).
- *Functions* are good for breaking up your code into more easily readable and maintainable pieces.
- This may come across as old school or pedantic, but lines longer than 80 characters are not recommended style for Python. Adjacent string literals (e.g "one""two") will be joined (even across newlines).

If I had to do what you're doing without `translate` (see below), I might do something like this (just a quick example, could probably be improved with a bit of work):

```
import string

def validate(alpha):
    # Is it exactly 26 characters long?
    if len(alpha) != 26: return False
    for c in alpha:
        # Is every character in [A-Z]?
        if c not in string.ascii_uppercase: return False
        # Is this character duplicated?
        if alpha.count(c) > 1: return False
    return True


alphabet = ""
while not validate(alphabet):
    alphabet = input("Please input the encryption alphabet in order (only A-Z"
                     " allowed, with no duplicates): ")

msg = input("Now input your encrypted message: ")

print("Your encrypted alphabet is:", alphabet)
print("Your encrypted message is:", msg)

# Create a mapping from one alphabet to the other using a dictionary
table = dict(zip(alphabet, string.ascii_uppercase))
cleartext = "".join([table[c] if c in table else c for c in msg])

print("Your decrypted message reads:", cleartext)
```

Lastly, you could also do this using Python's builtin string translation, like so:

```
import string
# read and validate alphabet
# read message
print(str.translate(message, str.maketrans(alphabet, string.ascii_uppercase)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are clobbering decrypt after you wrote all the scrambled letters into it:

```
crypt = ["*"] * 26
for s in range (26):
    val = decrypt[s] - 65
    crypt[val] = (s + 65)
```

Comment: this prints "IZTP TP QG 1PI PLNDLI QLPPSJL!" , it should print something along the lines of "THIS IS MY 1ST SECRET MESSAGE"

Comment: Commenting that section out gives you the **encrypt** code, which will take the string ``THIS IS MY 1ST SECRET MESSAGE!`` and turn it into ``VNKW KW BO 1WV WJHFJV BJWWXEJ!`` - the missing magic is the code to invert the contents of decrypt.

Comment: @Stobor is right I think.  newarr[decrypt[alphbet]]  or something like that, then use newarr to decrypt message.

Comment: @Jim: I've never used that before? I'm pretty sure that the scope of my assignment is supposed to be limited to while/for loops and basic lists and subscripts...

Comment: You are just using the value of an array to index another array.